# How can this be rephrased better?

Tags: phrases

Can anyone help we rephrase this better: "The respondent to the questions were identified to be inappropriate."

Comment: What is inappropriate here? The answers given? Or the person(s) answering? Respondent is a person. Do you intend to the say that the person was inappropriate? I suspect not, you probably mean "responses"

Comment: @Jim I wonder if the OP didn't mean to ask about __responses__ instead, which fits better with "were" and with "inappropriate."

Answer (score 1):

If there is **one** respondent:

> The respondent of the questions was deemed to be unsuitable.

As a side note, to help understand the use of "of" in this sentence, you can think of it like this: *The question's respondent*.

If there is **more than one** respondent:

> The respondents of the questions were deemed to be unsuitable.

Comment: This makes no sense.  What is a *respondent of the questions*??  There may be one or more respondents ***to*** a questionnaire, but it's not clear to me what the OP really means.

Comment: Note the use of "deemed" rather than "identified", an implication is that some degree of judgement is involved, and suitability or appropriateness probably requires such judgement. If it was a question of simple validity then identified would work. For example a question asking for a number answered with nonsense. How many cars do you own? Answered with "A Fish" could be identified as invalid.